# Happen Upon Robbery

Tags: meaning, grammar, usage

I have a question about the phrase "*happen on/upon*".  It seems that most dictionary say that "*happen on/upon*" should only be used with people or other inanimate objects, like these examples usages from a [dictionary](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/happen):

> She ***happened on*** a little cottage in the woods.
>   I ***happened upon*** them at the grocery store.

But on the web, I found this in a [newspaper](https://www.washingtonpost.com/local/crime/dc-police-officer-exchanges-gunfire-with-two-robbery-suspects/2015/07/22/42a7e846-30d9-11e5-97ae-30a30cca95d7_story.html):

> An off-duty D.C. police officer exchanged gunfire Tuesday night with two suspects after the officer ***happened upon*** a robbery and shooting of a man on a Northeast Washington street, police officials said.

A robbery is neither a person, nor an object.  So, is the usage in the newspaper wrong?

Comment: Nothing at the link tells you that the verb form _happen on/upon_ can only take a person or an object as its object.

Comment: "Happened upon *the scene*" is very common, and "a robbery" easily fits into the slot occupied by "the scene".  **A robbery** refers not only to a type of crime but to the *crime-in-progress*, which is semantically analogous to "the scene".

Comment: Definitions are extrapolated from usage. They are not *a priori*.

Answer (score 1):

You can "happen upon" an event.

The page you cite says "someone or something". A "thing" in this context could be an event or an idea, not necessarily an object.

"Walking through the park, I happened upon my friend Roger." "... a pretty blue rock." "... a jazz festival." "... a solution to a problem that has been bothering me for weeks."

In any case, I'd be cautious about drawing detailed conclusions like that from a dictionary definition. Try to write a dictionary-style definition of a word you know in your native language. Does it fully express all possible shades of meaning? Does it clearly indicate the context in which the word can be used? The answer is almost certainly "no". It's hard to write a good dictionary definition, and even those written by professionals often miss subtleties.